# Where is the status of a channel entry stored?

Tags: status

In my plugin query, I basically just want to know what the status of an entry is.

I checked `exp_channel_entries` and its not there.

I see status field in `exp_channel_entries_autosave` but the table is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `exp_channel_titles` - EE stashes its data all over the place.

Comment: Okay thanks. I see it now. Table name doesn't seem intuitive so I missed it.

Comment: Yeah, that schema can be a little difficult to get through sometimes ;)